# Fig tree leaf color lighter than usual

Tags: diseases, leaves, figs

Why does the fig tree (about 10x10x10feet in size) leaves have light green spots like this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you used for fertilizer?  Your plant is screaming chemistry deficiency: Iron, nitrogen is first in line for culpability.

Is this fig in a pot or in the large body of the garden soil?  What if anything have you added for chemistry (some people call this nutrients but not relevant to plants, they make their own food using the chemistry available with which to do photosynthesis.

Photosynthesis is the process plants use to make their own carbohydrates for energy.  For growth of MORE photosynthetic factories, immunity systems, reproductive growth, root growth and carbohydrate storage.  These chemicals are not food.

The leaf in your photo is turning off its photosynthetic factories.  Carbohydrate shortage.  Not enough energy to support those factories in that leaf so the plant goes into restriction mode.  The plant shuts down all the factories NOT ABLE to contribute to the whole of the plant.  Not enough light, not enough chemistry, too much or too little water, poor drainage.

That mulch you are using, wood chips, will be the first to be allocated any nitrogen in the soil.  Decomposers always get the nitrogen first.  Fact of life.  Any compost with a bit of nitrogen will only enjoy quicker, more complete decomposition with a little extra nitrogen.  When fully decomposed there won't be any nitrogen left for vegeys or whatever.  Compost is not fertilizer.  Wood chips are not decomposed and I would never call them compost nor would I use them to cover the surface of the soil.  THE CHIPS will suck up the nitrogen FIRST during their decomposition.  Fact of life.  I don't even put DECOMPOSED organic mulch/compost on top of my germinating seeds.  I only use sterilized soil when planting in pots, I mean always.  I don't add fertilizer until my starts need up potting or my plants are between 2 and 3rd sets of leaves.  Compost is NOT fertilizer.  Compost is not a soil substitute.  Chips are not compost or mulch in my opinion.  Lots of definitions of words we use need more refinement and standardization.  Permaculture; Permanent no work Culture of plants that will sustain themselves is an oxymoron.  Permanent and Culture are opposite ends of the definition spectrum.

Comment: This guy is a pretty big tree and I didn't cover the soil right below the tree with any thing just soil

Comment: That is fine.  You don't need to cover the soil at the base of a tree.  It helps conserve moisture, smother weeds...not a big deal.  That is one gorgeous tree.  I am seeing it needs water, it is wilting slightly. It also needs some basic fertilizer, a tree stake or something.  Balanced fertilizer NPK.  The soil looks hydrophobic which means that soil will shed not absorb water.  I would get a 3" PVC pipe, 3 foot long, drill 1/2 inch holes all over 2 feet of it, shove it into the ground no farther than 3 feet from the trunk and fill it with water to water this tree.  I would do at least 2 pipes